# How to explicitly configure 'Content-Type' in Gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, mime-types, content-type, babeljs

Due to recent browser change, I'm experiencing `Refused to execute script because its MIME type is not executable` and this issue comes and goes away on its own.

I want to be able to explicitly configure the `Content-Type` to be application/javascript for all script files so my server won't request wrong MIME type in the response header.

I have a website built in Babel package using Gulp. Where can I configure this? I've seen examples for Express Node project [JavaScript MIME type is application/octet-stream nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059530/javascript-mime-type-is-application-octet-stream-nodejs) but not one for Babel project.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite common.

Your suggested approach is not recommended. All you are doing is masking a problem that *will* eventually bite you.

Look in the network panel for any request that produces that error. Look at the content that is transferred to the browser for that request. You'll see that it is probably your `index.html` (or equivalent) file.

The reason for this is because most Single Page Apps will re-direct every unfound request to the `index.html` or a `404.html` (or equivalent) file. (The server feature is called url-rewriting).

So, the bottom line is that the error actually indicates an unfound resource that returns as MIME type `html` while you request a MIME type of `js`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My error complains that it's `binary/octet-stream` even though my scripts are plain `application/javascript`. What do you suggest to fix this?

Comment: What is shown in the network as the content downloaded from the server?

Comment: Right now it's showing as text/javascript and the error is gone but I don't think this will permanently stay this way as this error came back yesterday and resolved on its own in a few hours.

Comment: Please remove one of the JS files in question (temporarily), then check the network panel when you get the error.

Comment: Let's say temporarily removing one file solves a problem but what would be the next step? I will need that js file.

Comment: This is a trouble isolation step, not a solution step. Trying to isolate.